# What's the use of const variable members in C++?

Tags: c++, constants

Are there any scenarios where a const variable member is useful in C++?

If you want to make an immutable class, the usual approach is to declare private members with get-only const functions to access their values. This has the advantage that the class can be copy assigned and so on. So in this case you don't need const variable members.

On the other hand, if the class has a const member variable, it won't get an automatic copy assignment operator. I don't see an scenario where this would be useful.

Comment: _"If you want to make an immutable object, the usual approach is to declare private member with get-only const functions to access their values."_ Where did you hear that?

Comment: *"This has the advantage that the class can be copy assigned"* if you want an object to remain **constant**, that's a disadvantage.  It's a point of failure.

Comment: If you can assign a new value to an object, it's not immutable.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I think the confussion was because I used "object" instead of "class". I fixed that.

Answer (score 2):

A main advantage of a `const` data member is the same as with a reference member (indeed a reference can be usefully thought of as a `const` pointer), namely that it *forces initialization*, unless the member is of a type with a user-defined default constructor. The compiler will insist on initialization. Still, I've never found that so useful that I've started doing it.

An alternative, if guaranteed initialization is what one desires, is to wrap the data member in a class that does not provide default construction. With this approach the data member can be assigned to, if it supports assignment.

Another advantage (of a `const` data member) is that it expresses an *intended constraint*, with compiler checking, and that's almost always good. The more constraints on how values can change, the less there is to consider to understand or debug the code.

Answer (score 0):

Once you initialize a variable `const` then you never can re-initialized it. Each later attempt to re-initialize the `const` variable will produce a compilation error.

It is helpful when you want to prevent the accidental modification of some variable which you never want to be change. Like in mathematics we need PI, we can declared it as a constant -

```
private const double PI = 3.1416;
```

Comment: Comments purged as they were not constructive.